# is it possible to create forms like registration forms using p[hp code in joomla1.6?if yes,where the codes are write&which database is used for this?

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I create a  website in joomla1.6 by simpling changing the modules&template.Is there a way to create website which contain forms like registration form,searching form etc by using php code.if it possible,where the code to be write? and is it needed to create database for these forms?

Comment: Joomla has a registration page...

Answer (score 0):

There are many extensions available for joomla for creating/managing forms. Have you tried search before?

For examples, see the joomla directory - http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/forms

EDIT [More details based on comments]

Joomla can be extended to do what you want using extensions. There are extensions for creating forms from the admin page. The link I've mentioned before is the directory where you can choose extensions from. What you need to do now is

- Select one of the extensions. Such as http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/forms/1508
- Install the extension in your joomla installation
- Access the extension from your admin page to create any sort of form you need

With this, you won't even have to write any PHP code.

Comment: I make the Super Users filter type in the article manager as no filtering.what is the next step i need to do for including a registration form in my article.

Comment: i can't understood.could you explain the steps for creating my own registration form in joomla1.6